# Rewriting multiple near identical queries with different where clauses

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a collection of queries like this:

```
variable a = select field1 from table where field2 = 1
variable b = select field1 from table where field2 = 2
variable c = select field1 from table where field2 = 3
variable d = select field1 from table where field2 = 4
```

Later, some work is done and these variables are used depending on certain values, in this way:

```
if aieou1 <> 0 then
CallProc(something, something else, something else, a)
end if

if aeiou2 <> 0 then
CallProc(something, something else, something else, b)
end if

if aieou3 <> 0 then
CallProc(something, something else, something else, c)
end if

if aeiou4 <> 0 then
CallProc(something, something else, something else, d)
end if
```

This seems pretty horrible to me. Four near identical queries, in both sections, which only have minor differences. What is a better way to rewrite this? Note, if it makes a difference, "table" from the first four queries only has around 12 rows (and will likely never have more).

Comment: Currently, I think I need the multiple variables. The only "clean up" I see at least is to use one query and have case statements. But I'm hoping I could clean it up further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only run one query, then loop over the results of the query to determine what to do. e.g. something like:

```
FOR r IN (
  select field1, field2 from table where field2 in (1,2,3,4)
) LOOP
  CASE r.field2
  WHEN 1 THEN a := r.field1;
  WHEN 2 THEN b := r.field1;
  WHEN 3 THEN c := r.field1;
  WHEN 4 THEN d := r.field1;
  END CASE;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have bind variable and do like the below

```
variable a = select field1 from table where field2 =:bind_variable
```

Then you can pass the different values 1,2,3,4 to the bind variable

Answer (score 0):

You can have one SELECT statement that queries for all the 4 rows (types from 1 to 4) at once and read it through a cursor instead of assigning in-line to a, b, c and d through four separate queries. Once you read each row via the cursor,  you can get the value for each type and possibly make the corresponding call ( if it is not too early for that).

Another reason to use a cursor instead is that it avoids context switches, which might be "relatively expensive" on non Windows hosts with large SGAs.